# Tailwind preset is not loaded

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a React project inside a monorepo that is setup with tailwind

I am setting up a preset file at the root of the project :

`tailwind.preset.js`

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extends: {
      colors: {
        red: {
          1: '#FF2B52',
          2: '#FF5575',
          3: '#FF8097',
          4: '#FFAABA',
        },
      },
    }
 }
```

Now, I want to use this preset in my project I do :

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    join(__dirname, 'src/**/!(*.stories|*.spec).{ts,tsx,html}'),
    ...createGlobPatternsForDependencies(__dirname),
  ],
  presets: [require(join(__dirname, '../../tailwind.preset'))],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
};
```

now, When I use a class in my project

```
<div className="text-red-1">Test</div>
```

it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Shouldn't your `presets` property in `tailwind.config.js` reference your `tailwind.preset.js` file? It looks like you're currently pointing to the file `tailwind.config`.

Comment: yeah sorry copy paste problem on this slack post I fixeds

Comment: I think you'll want to use the full filename, `tailwind.preset.js` and also verify the path to that file.